# Return raster that intersects another raster in gdal

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to programmatically orthorectify a bunch of Rasters (.ntf format), however I need a DEM that covers each raster in order to do so.

I have DEM rasters (.tif) as tiles that cover the entire region I'm trying to orthorectify, but I need an automated way to find which tiled DEM covers each individual scene. The tiles are Projected in Albers Equal Area Conic while the scenes that need to be orthorectified are in GCS84.

Something similar to 'Select by Location' in Arc (but for rasters) would be preferable but after searching the web it doesn't seem like this exists in GDAL.

I can get the Corner Coordinates of the DEM .tif from 'gdalinfo', and I can get the x and y max/min coordinates of the .ntf raster from its associated .xml file...

However the coordinates for the DEM from gdalinfo are Projected and the coordinates for the .ntf from the xml file are Geographic.

Previously I had just mosaicked the tile DEM pieces together and then used gdalwarp to clip the mosaicked DEM to the to-be-orthorectified scene's extent, but for this particular process the area is way too large to do this.

Any thoughts as to how I can (simply) find the intersecting DEM raster for each .ntf scene?

Comment: Use gdalbuildvrt for building a virtual DEM mosaic.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that. I'll try it.